# Карусель карточек bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Необходимо сделать вывод карточек в карусель.
Я сделал вот такую вот
[image: Первый]

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($news)/3; $i++)
            if($i == 0):
      ?>
                    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?=$i;?>" class="active"></li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?=$i;?>"></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
            </ul>
            <!-- The slideshow -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i = $i + 3)
            if($i == 0):
      ?>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="card-deck">
                                    <div class="card card-red">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <p class="card-date">
                                                <?=$news[$i]['postDate'];?>
                                            </p>
                                            <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i]['title'];?></h5>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <p class="card-date">
                                                <?=$news[$i+1]['postDate'];?>
                                            </p>
                                            <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i+1]['title'];?></h5>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card card-purp ">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <p class="card-date">
                                                <?=$news[$i+2]['postDate'];?>
                                            </p>
                                            <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i+2]['title'];?></h5>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="card-deck">
                                        <div class="card card-red">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <p class="card-date">
                                                    <?=$news[$i]['postDate'];?>
                                                </p>
                                                <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i]['title'];?></h5>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <p class="card-date">
                                                    <?=$news[$i+1]['postDate'];?>
                                                </p>
                                                <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i+1]['title'];?></h5>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card card-purp ">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <p class="card-date">
                                                    <?=$news[$i+2]['postDate'];?>
                                                </p>
                                                <h5 class="card-title"><?=$news[$i+2]['title'];?></h5>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-details">Подробнее</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
        </div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы не было

этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
? :( помогите, пожалуйста

https://github.com/lordSerega/redEdge

Comment: вероятно запрос к базе вернул только 7 новостей

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов, да, запрос вернул 7 новостей. А как сделать так, чтобы в блоках, где нет новостей, ничего не было? :(

Comment: 1 вариант дополнить пустышками count($news)%3 раз

Comment: 2 вариант поставить проверку isset($news[$i+1]) . Первый менее трудозатратен

Comment: а можете подробней про первый? :(

Comment: повторное использование кода явно не про вас. вас не посещает мысль выводить эту шляпу в цикле ?

Comment: после 9 строчки

    for($i=0;$i<count($news)%3;$i++){
        $news[]=array('postDate'=>'','title'=>'');
    }

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов, тогда кнопки не будут скрыты :(